# Angular: Handling Forms to POST Add data to backend

Tags: angular

I'm a novice in Angular and I'm developing an app. I have a form where the data must be added to the DB. But there seems to be something wrong with when the frontend tries to send the form data using the services method.

```
<h2>Add Bids</h2>
<div>
  <form nz-form [formGroup]="validateForm" class="add-bid-form" (ngSubmit)="submitForm()">

    <nz-form-item>
      <nz-form-label [nzSm]="6" [nzXs]="24" nzFor="amount" nzRequired>Transportation cost</nz-form-label>
      <nz-form-control [nzSm]="14" [nzXs]="24">
        <input nz-input type="text" id="amount" formControlName="amount"  />
      </nz-form-control>
    </nz-form-item>

// other input fields in the same format as above

    <div nz-row nzJustify="center">
      <div nz-col nzFlex="3">
        <nz-form-control [nzSpan]="14" [nzOffset]="6">
          <button nz-button nzType="primary"
                  (click)="addBids()"
          >Add Payment</button>
        </nz-form-control>
      </div>
      <div nz-col nzFlex="2">
        <button nz-button nzType="default" routerLink="/dashboard">
          Go To Dashboard
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </form>
</div>
```

The TS  file methods:

```
 // Form Data validation handler
  formData(): any{
    return this.validateForm.value;
  }

  addBids(): any {
    // tslint:disable-next-line:forin
    // const bidId = this.formData().bidId;
    const amount = this.formData().amount;
    const description = this.formData().description;
    const requisitionId = null;
    const supplierId = this.formData().supplierId;

    this.backendService.addBid(amount, description, requisitionId, supplierId)
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.bidData = data;
        console.log(data);
      });
  }
```

For reference this is the service:

```
  addBid(amount, description, requisitionId, supplierId): any {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    });
    return this.http
      .post(this.uri + '/bid/add', { amount, description, requisitionId, supplierId }, {headers})
      .pipe(catchError(this.errorHandler));
  }
```

Appreciate any insight on this issue thanks!

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Any error, which the console prints? Please elaborate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The form in your view is handled by the function named submitForm()

```
<form nz-form [formGroup]="validateForm" class="add-bid-form" (ngSubmit)="submitForm()">
```

Whilst the button is bound to addBids()

```
<button nz-button nzType="primary"
                  (click)="addBids()"
```

I recommend you to choose one of those, not both.

Comment: I agree. I would move the addBids logic to the submitForm function and make the button a submit button